# How Get The middle point of an ArcSegment in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the best solution for getting the middle point of an ArcSegment in a path and label it in WPF?

[image]

Comment: Good question. I'd assume that you have to calculate it based on some combination of radius and midpoints?

Comment: If the arc is somehow data-bound to a viewmodel, then you can either add a property with the correct position of the label to the viewmodel, or implement a converter that does the same. On the other hand, if you are not using data-binding, then you can simply compute to the position of the label  in the same place where you compute the parameters for the arc. As **Ritch** pointed out you can calculate the position based on the endpoints, radius and angle...

Comment: Maybe [Charle Petzold's blog](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/01/Mathematics-of-ArcSegment.html) will be somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
        //the given arc (or any other segments)
        var arc = new ArcSegment(
            point: new Point(200, 100),
            size: new Size(100, 50),
            rotationAngle: 90,
            isLargeArc: true,
            sweepDirection: SweepDirection.Counterclockwise,
            isStroked: true);

        //compose one or more segments into a collection
        var pathcoll = new PathSegmentCollection();
        pathcoll.Add(arc);

        //create a figure based on the set of segments
        var figure = new PathFigure();
        figure.Segments = pathcoll;

        //compose a collection of figures
        var figcoll = new PathFigureCollection();
        figcoll.Add(figure);

        //create a path-geometry using the figures collection
        var geom = new PathGeometry(figcoll);

        double fraction = 0.5;  //the relative point of the curve
        Point pt;               //the absolute point of the curve
        Point tg;               //the tangent point of the curve
        geom.GetPointAtFractionLength(
            fraction,
            out pt,
            out tg);
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: 'GetPointAtFractionLength'.this is exactly what I was needed! thanks.

Comment: several hours of searching later and here we are!  Thanks!

Comment: GetPointAtFractionLength has solved so many problems for me. Great find!